# Unpermitted parameters in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers, strong-parameters

I read about `collection_check_boxes` but I don't understand how can I set the checked values.
I have the following model:

```
class Objective < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :indicators
  has_many :objective_children, class_name: "Objective", foreign_key: "parent_id"

  def objective_ids
    objective_children.collect{|o| o.id}
  end

  def objective_ids= objectives_ids
    objectives_ids.each do |id|
      objective_children << Objective.find(id)
    end
  end
end
```

edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@objective) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :objective_ids, Objective.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

the html checkbox are ok but I don't know how to set the values to `objective`. I was tried define `objective_ids= objectives_ids` but nothing happens.

In Controller:

```
class ObjectivesController < ApplicationController
    def objective_params
      params.require(:objective).permit(:name, :code, :description, :objective_ids)
    end
end
```

**EDIT**
The log file says `Unpermitted parameters: perspective_id, objective_ids`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved changing the line

```
params.require(:objective).permit(:name, :code, :description, :objective_ids)
```

to

```
params.require(:objective).permit(:name, :code, :description, :objective_ids => [])
```

Comment: It can also be written as `.permit(:name, :code, :description, objective_ids: [])`

Comment: This works as long as you have :objective_ids => [] as the last element. If you put it between other symbols, you get a syntax error. Those who saw the syntax error, place it as the last element and the error will go away.

Answer (score 3):

I get the same problem, try this line:

```
params.require(:objective).permit(:name, :code, :description, :objective_ids => [])
```

but does not work and i change to:

```
params.require(:objective).permit(:name, :code, :description, {:objective_ids => []})
```

and it works !!