# Iterating through associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, rails-activerecord

Having set up a has_many through relationship, I'm trying to iterate through associated B objects in the view of an object A. I.e. something like

```
<% for q in @survey.questions do %>
  <%= q.name %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

yields nothing, while

```
<%= @survey.questions %>
```

yields

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Question:0x007f9859f221e8>
```

How could (should) I access these?

---

Here's the Controller

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.update(survey_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to surveys_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

---

And here's the Models

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :questions, through: :assignments
end
```

.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :surveys, through: :assignments
end
```

.

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: Can you please add your model and controller code to the question?

Comment: how is @survey defined?

Comment: Fixed this with a combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982904/unpermitted-parameters-in-rails-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436264/how-to-use-rails-4-strong-parameters-with-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% @survey.questions.each do |q| %>
  <%= q.name %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

The for loop should be avoided in Ruby.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032875/syntax-for-a-for-loop-in-ruby), it looks like for loops operate on arrays, so something like this might also work (again, this is not the recommended solution):

```
<% for q in @survey.questions.to_a do %>
  <%= q.name %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Update

I think you need to make your associations singular in the Assignment model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I created a [quiz on many to many relationships](http://www.codequizzes.com/topics/3/quizzes/54) that you might find helpful.

Comment: Sorry! That'll teach me not to copypaste everything. They actually were singular. Updating the post to reflect it.

Comment: Looking at your guide (thanks!) could it be something to do with attr_accessible? I.e. do I have to make the :name in the Question class accessible?

Comment: Btw, I went through your guide and it led to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461916/problems-getting-has-many-x-through-y-to-work-in-the-console

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell Powers answer should work.  Try checking if the @survey actually has any questions. Add this in the page somewhere  `<%= @survey.questions.count %>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `@survey` in question really has assignments associated to it? Can you see them on the Rails console?